# Merge some part of the list together using python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, concatenation

I have a very interesting problem that I need to solve.

Assume that I have a string in the following format:

```
input = ['opst tops', 'opst opts', 'opst pots', 'eip pie', 'eip epi']
```

The above string will help me find anagrams of words. For example, the word "tops" has signiature "opts", meanwhile, the word "opts" also has signiature "opst" ... Hence, all words has signiature "opst" should be grouped together, as followed. The output is the word anagram class.

```
output = ['tops opts pots', 'pie epi']
```

I am new to python and I'd appreciate if you can help. Sorry about the confusion and hope this make sense.

Comment: did you tried something?

Comment: is it supposed to be: raw = ['opst tops', 'opst opts', 'opst pots', 'eip pie', 'eip epi']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for ease, to collect your words:

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = defaultdict(list)
for entry in raw:
    key, word = entry.split()
    words[key].append(word)

raw = [' '.join(v) for v in words.values()]
```

The `defaultdict` makes the code cleaner here; it's just a subclass of `dict` that will call the factory (here set to `list`) if a key doesn't yet exist. Without a `defaultdict` you'd have to use:

```
words = {}
```

and in the loop:

```
words.setdefault(key, []).append(word)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> raw = ['opst tops', 'opst opts', 'opst pots', 'eip pie', 'eip epi']
>>> words = defaultdict(list)
>>> for entry in raw:
...     key, word = entry.split()
...     words[key].append(word)
... 
>>> [' '.join(v) for v in words.values()]
['pie epi', 'tops opts pots']
```

If your input list is sorted and order is important, you can also use [`itertools.groupb()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

raw = [' '.join(w.split()[1] for w in words) 
       for key, words in groupby(raw, key=lambda e: e.split()[0])]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [' '.join(w.split()[1] for w in words) 
...        for key, words in groupby(raw, key=lambda e: e.split()[0])]
['tops opts pots', 'pie epi']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for s in raw:
    sig, val = s.split(' ')
    d[sig].append(val)
res = [' '.join(val) for val in d.values()]
```

Note that using a dictionary means the "signatures" may not come out in the order they went in.